# My onClickListener work inside a getView method. Why?

Tags: android, android-listview

I was setting the onClickListener for the ListView, and I have set it in each activity at first and it works. For fun I thought of trying to set onClickListener somewhere else to find more then one solution. So I write the onCLickListener in the getView method of the arrayAdapter.

```
  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //Checking if there is a View present for reusing if not inflate one.
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
    }

    //getting the current position of the word object in the View
    final Word currentWord = getItem(position);

    //getting the text view resource for setting our desired text.
    TextView mivok = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.mivokTranslation);

    mivok.setText(currentWord.getmMiwokTrans());

    TextView defaultTran = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.defaultTranslation);

    defaultTran.setText(currentWord.getmDefaultTrans());

    ImageView imageView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

     //Checking if the View has an Image resource, if yes then setting the correct image.
    if (currentWord.checkImageResource == 0) {
        imageView.setImageResource(currentWord.getmImageResource());

    } else {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    // Set the theme color for the list item
    View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container);
    // Find the color that the resource ID maps to
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId);
    // Set the background color of the text container View
    textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);

   listItemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),currentWord.getmAudioResource());
           mediaPlayer.start();
       }
   });

    return listItemView;
}
```

While doing I though it won't work. Because as far as I have understood the getView method it set the view on the listView when we return the listItemView at th end. But it worked how can a clickListener event response to an activity that is yet to be added.

Comment: It might be overshadowed by another view. Make sure theres nothing else who's capturing the onClick event before listItemView has a chance to handle it.

Comment: @TiagoDávila No, there is not overshadowing in my code.

Comment: Could you post your list item xml? Im pretty sure that there is overlapping on views. For instance, try to add an on click listener to your imageView object. Pretty sure it will work.

Comment: It is working, i was asking why it is working, but that doubt is cleared now.

Comment: Yup. Views are built upon a hyerarchy. So views on top handle touch first and does not trigger lower layers. Best of luck on your development.

Comment: Thank you, Best luck to you to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside getView you simply assign a listener to the returned view. Why would it have not worked? It doesn't matter when you assign a listener - it's an object of anonymous class that is "saved" by the view for later use.

Comment: Isn't getView return one view at a time, then before returning a view how can it response to clickListener

Comment: It doesn't matter when you assign a listener. It will work, because listener is a normal object (anonymous) assigned to view. When view is displayed and you click it, there is a check if any listener is set and if so, it's executed. If I helped you please accept the answer, thanks.

Comment: So, after it is displayed through getView, if there is a click Event, it will again come back to the getView method and execute the code.

Comment: Simply speaking yes. Read more about anonymous classes for more details.